# A one-pixel hairline appears at the top edge of toolbar in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitoolbar

I switched my app from xcode 4.6 to 5.

I have added UIToolBar at right side of navigationbar having 3 buttons and I have used following code for that.

```
UIToolbar* tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -25, 135, 44)];
    //[tools setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:54/255.0f green:54/255.0f blue:54/255.0f alpha:0.0]];

    [tools setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    //[tools setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [tools setAlpha:0.0f];
    [tools setClearsContextBeforeDrawing:YES];
    [tools setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [tools setTranslucent:YES];

    [tools setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"historyBg.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionTop barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [tools setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"historyBg.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionTop];
    // Create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
    NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

    //Create volume control button
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(volumeControlButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icnVolumeControl.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem* bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    volumeControl = bi;

    [buttons addObject:bi];

    //Creates mute volume control button
    btnToggleMute = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnToggleMute.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    [btnToggleMute addTarget:self action:@selector(ToggleSound:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnToggleMute.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
    [btnToggleMute setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icnMuteVolume.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnToggleMute setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icnNotMute.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnToggleMute];
    [buttons addObject:bi];

    button  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(playLastPlayedVideo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icnQuickPlay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icnQuickPlay@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    [buttons addObject:bi];

    // stick the buttons in the toolbar
    [tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];

    // and put the toolbar in the nav bar
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
```

**The problem is** a one-pixel hairline appears at the top edge in iOS 7. I tried all functions background color, tint color, shadow image, etc..Nothing solved my problem.

I also referred this [transition guidelines for bars in ios 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html).

I found that there it is mentioned under Bars section against appearance property that a one-pixel hairline appears at the top edge in iOS 7 but it is annoying and if someone dont want that it should get removed.

Any solution to remove that line?

it looks like this

[image: how it looks like]

Comment: Try investigating view hierarchy with http://revealapp.com, it helps.

Comment: Removing shadow image like this didn't help ?
  `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];`

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii thanx,A great tool , I was not knowing about that tools, it is showing that it is part of UIToolBar itself. But not able to get root of problem.

Comment: @iNoob thanx for your quick reply but that does not solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to MANIAK_dobrii for suggesting a great tool **revealapp**, by the help of that tool I found that in UIToolBar subviews hierarchy , there was an one UIImageView resulting in a gray colour line at top of UIToolBar.

I made it invisible using following code

```
    [tools setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    for(UIView *view in [tools subviews])
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            {
                [view setHidden:YES];
                [view setAlpha:0.0f];
            }
        }
```

And solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Storyboards....way easy to keep track of that stuff..without the extra app.  Here is a snapshot of the iPhone storyboard.  View, button, label hierarchy on left.....individual adjustments for views, buttons, and labels on right side in 'attributes inspector'[image: Xcode screenshot]

Comment: You cant see subviews(built in or default) inside toolBars or other uicontrols by using view hierarchy on left side. And here storyboard does not make any difference.